# how to check how many times retry function called in python

Tags: python, pytest, decorator, retry-logic

I'm using a retry decorator to run the test case if failed. So, want to know how many times the retry function called

```
   def retry(tries=3, delay=10):
       def decorator(func):
           @wraps(func)
           def func_retry(*args, **kwargs):
              n_tries, n_delay = tries, delay
              output = error = None
              while n_tries >= 1:
                  try:
                      output = func(*args, **kwargs)
                      return output
                  except AssertionError as e:
                      n_tries = n_tries - 1
                      error = e.__str__()
                      print(f'Retry error: "{func.__name__}" due to "{error}". So, Retrying execution [{(tries - n_tries)}/{tries}] in {delay} second(s)...')
                      time.sleep(n_delay)
                   return output
           return func_retry
       return decorator
```

Sample function for testing purpose

```
   @retry()
   def test():
      assert "x" == "y"
```

I want to know how many times retry function in retry decorator called
like retry.count or retry.tries

Answer (score 2):

You can work with attributes of the final function that is returned. (You can also do it on the decorator but then it is not accessible from the outside).

```
def retry(tries=3, delay=10):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def func_retry(*args, **kwargs):
           func_retry.n_tries = 0
           output = error = None
           while func_retry.n_tries < tries:
               try:
                   output = func(*args, **kwargs)
                   return output
               except AssertionError as e:
                   func_retry.n_tries += 1
                   error = e.__str__()
                   print(f'Retry error: "{func.__name__}" due to "{error}". So, Retrying execution [{(func_retry.n_tries)}/{tries}] in {delay} second(s)...')
                   time.sleep(delay)
           return output
        func_retry.n_tries = 0 # set initial attribute
        return func_retry
    return decorator

@retry(tries=5, delay=0.1)
def foo():
   assert 1==2

print("Tries done", foo.n_tries)
foo()
print("Tries done", foo.n_tries)
```

Output:

```
Tries done 0
Retry error: "foo" due to "". So, Retrying execution [1/5] in 0.1 second(s)...
Retry error: "foo" due to "". So, Retrying execution [2/5] in 0.1 second(s)...
Retry error: "foo" due to "". So, Retrying execution [3/5] in 0.1 second(s)...
Retry error: "foo" due to "". So, Retrying execution [4/5] in 0.1 second(s)...
Retry error: "foo" due to "". So, Retrying execution [5/5] in 0.1 second(s)...
Tries done 5
```

Comment: when test case is passed foo.n_tries returns 0, when failed starts from 0. But I need passed scenarios should returns 0 and failed scenarios should return same as retry count

Comment: Can you elaborate? When it fails the amount increases and if it works it stays at 0.